# How to make rotations rotateY and rotateX at different times?

Tags: jquery, css, rotation, transform, transition

I made a div that rotates by 180 degrees over .5 seconds but I don't know how to change the time.
I'm using `transition: all .5s linear;` to make the effect but I don't want it to be `all`. I just want it to affect rotation. I tried `transition: transform .5s linear` but this affects all rotations and my problem is that I want to know how to affect the `rotateY` and `rotateX` values separately.
Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/VanillaLore/wsuzzguu/4/

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but this tutorial might help: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/

Answer (score 0):

You can't target each individually, as they are subsets of the `transform` property. You can only animate the `transform` property.

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug from your code, fixed it, and maybe here is what you need:   http://jsfiddle.net/abruzzi/zndwy12t/

```
.face.back {
  /* the code below should be removed*/
  /* transform: rotateY(180deg); */
  background-color: blue;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    margin:1px;
}
```